# Transmitting message with UART in STM32 Nucleo using Eclipse

Tags: stm32, uart

I'm trying to send sample text for making sure that `UART_GPIO_Transmit` function works well. I'm using two char arrays:

```
char aMESSAGE[8] = "WHATEVER";
char bMESSAGE[10] = "0123456789";
```

and this code for UART transmission:

```
HAL_UART_Transmit(&UartHandle, &aMESSAGE,10, 0xFFF);
HAL_UART_Transmit(&UartHandle, &bMESSAGE,10, 0xFFF);
```

Using screen in Mac OS X for viewing the serial output. However, I see this:

```
W��TE�ER�12�4��78�
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on receiving side, screen has probably enabled parity checking and your MCU program don't set parity for transmitting, so in your example all characters with `even parity` are not accepted and you see `?`

Or the problem could be also on opposite side that MCU set parity and computer don't accept characters with zero stop bit.

Comment: Yes it was about the parameters mismatch as you said. I changed the parity  and data bits from 8 to 7 as I was using 1 stop bit.